# YAMLException: bad indentation of a mapping entry

Tags: node.js, yaml

In the OpenAPI definition below, the parameter LayoutId causes the parser error "bad indentation of a mapping entry".

Yaml File:

```
---
name: 1x1+1x1_1x1  
  LayoutId: 3A1B6753-4F92-4DCD-A1E3-6462374EC897
  LayoutType: ControlRoomGrid
  ConfiguredSegments:
    SegmentConfiguration:
      Height: 50
      Id: None
      Left: 0
      SerializationId: true
      Top: 0
      Width: 50
      Index: 0
    SegmentConfiguration:
      Height: 50
      Id: None
      Left: 0
      SerializationId: true
      Top: 50
      Width: 50
      Index: 0
    SegmentConfiguration:
      Height: 100
      Id: None
      Left: 50
      SerializationId: true
      Top: 0
      Width: 50
      Index: 0
  IntendedResolution:
    Height:
      100
    Width:
      100
  PlaneType: A
---
```

I have spent almost an hour to solve this and am not able to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create an object like that. If you want to create an object named `name` you should use it like this:

```
name:  
  LayoutId: 3A1B6753-4F92-4DCD-A1E3-6462374EC897
  LayoutType: ControlRoomGrid
  ConfiguredSegments:
    ...
```

Otherwise, If you don't want to create an object named `name`, you need to keep the `name` field and the other fields in the same line.

```
name: 1x1+1x1_1x1  
LayoutId: 3A1B6753-4F92-4DCD-A1E3-6462374EC897
LayoutType: ControlRoomGrid
ConfiguredSegments:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and here is how i got it resolved: Check the "whitespaces" in the YAML file. The indentation should be done with "spaces" and not "tabs".

"whitespaces" can be switched on in any text editor. e.g. in VS code the "whitespaces" can be turned on by: "In the search bar on the settings page, search for Render Whitespace and with the dropdown that appears select all , this will then show all whitespace characters. "

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34675516)

Answer (score -1):

```css
ul{
width: 300px;
height: 80px;
background: #F6F1E9;
}
li{
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>It's a broken yarn.lock file issue. To solve this issue:</p>
<ul>
<li>Delete yarn.lock file</li>
<li>Run 'yarn install'</li>
<li>Run 'yarn start'</li>
</ul>

<p>Also, ensure that you have a stable internet connection</p>
```

Comment: Did you mean this answer for a different question? This looks like it's about something else.